# How can I access files on Windows Server from using a web proxy Pfsense?

Tags: networking, proxy, pfsense

I have over 25 pc's all with W7 and XP, using a web proxy based on Pfsense. Someone told me(my boss) that I need to open the port 445 to access the Windows Server 2012 R2 that is located in another building, with different segment

E.g

my pc is 10.15.1.x
I need to access to \145.130.100.y

Normally, avoiding the gateway of my proxy, i can surf that shared folder, but when i changed that gateway, i cannot access and \145.130.100.y shows me an error that that folder is "unavailable"

Any ideas? Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

Try to open ports from 135 through 139 TCP and UDP

Plus check if 445 is open also for TCP and UDP